# After I upgrade to Solr4.10, the SolrJ return SolrDocument as NULL

Tags: solr, null, solrj

I upgrade to the `Solr 4.10` this week.

I can query data from Solr with the `Solr admin page`.

I can query data from Solr with the `URL` [127.0.0.1/solr/core/dismax?] in the browser.

But when I use `Solrj`(4.10) to query the data, in the results, the SolrDocument is *NULL*.

By the way, the numFound in the results of QueryResponse is set correctlly.

And the same code runs well when I query to a Solr4.5 server

Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: show your SolrJ usage, probably you do something wrong.

Comment: Did you rebuild your index?

Comment: To Bohemian: Maybe the "upgrade" is not right. The Solr 4.10 is new, and the index is new, so I donot need rebuild the index

Comment: To Mysterion, the code runs well in Solr4.5.

Comment: It is hard to say without an example of request/response... but could this be related to [SOLR-6501](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6501)?

Could you try it with 4.10.1 version of [solrj](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/solr/solr-solrj/4.10.1/) and [solr](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/solr/solr/4.10.1/)?

Comment: To rchukh: Thank you very much! The reason is same with SOLR-6501! Thanks again! I will try it again with Solrj 4.10.1 and Solr 4.10.1